# Copying 2YUV Video Streams in FFmpeg

Tags: video, ffmpeg

I have noticed that when I copy 2vuy video streams with FFmpeg, the files are different in Quicktime.  I am using the below command:

```
ffmpeg -i infile.mov -vcodec copy -acodec copy outfile.mov
```

In the Quicktime Movie Inspector, the infile is listed as **8 bit Packed YUV 4:2:2 (2vuy)**.  The outfile is listed as **'2vuy'**.

Has anyone else dealt with this?  Thanks in advance for any responses.

Comment: Can you provide the full FFmpeg command output?